# AVE vs MAX data usage and requirements?

Tags: r, function, max, average

So I have a data set and I am looking to find the maximum depth of the epilimnion (indicated by space between the first depth value '0' and 'T') 
So for example, site 'A' would have a max depth of '2' and site 'B' would be '5'.

```
SITE_ID DEPTH METALIMNION TEMP_FIELD 
  A      0                    25.0            
  A      1                    26.0
  A      2                    27.0
  B      0                    10.0
  B      5         T          9.0
  B      10                   11.0
  B      15        B          21.0
```

For this same data set I found the average temperature of the epilimnion using

```
g <- with(df, ave(as.character(METALIMNION), SITE_ID, 
          FUN = function(x) {
            x[is.na(x)] <- ""
            rev(cumsum(rev(x) == "T"))
            }))
df$EPI.T <- ave(df$TEMP_FIELD, df$SITE_ID, g)
```

However, when trying to use the 'max' function, the code does not work.

```
df$EPI.D <- max(df$DEPTH, df$SITE_ID, g)
```

Does 'max' require a different kind of data than 'ave'?
 Ideal final set of data:

```
SITE_ID DEPTH METALIMNION TEMP_FIELD EPI.T EPI.D
  A      0                    25.0   26.0   2     
  A      1                    26.0   26.0   2
  A      2                    27.0   26.0   2
  B      0                    10.0   10.25  5
  B      5         T          9.0    10.25  5
  B      10                   11.0   10.25  5
  B      15        B          21.0   10.25  5
```

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at `10.25` as `EPI.T` for `SITE_ID == "B"`?When I run your code, it does not produce that. The `ave(df$TEMP_FIELD, df$SITE_ID, g)` returns `[1] 26.0 26.0 26.0  9.5  9.5 16.0 16.0`. Are you absolutely sure the code does what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you arrive at your averages/means, I do *not* get the same results when running your code. Anyway, your `max(...)` approach do not work because `max(...)` is nothing like `avg(...)` (which is a function to apply a function over groups). `max(...)` simply computes the maximum value of a vector of values. In that sense, `max(...)` is more like `mean(...)`, and not like `avg(...)`.

The following findes the maximal values of `DEPTH` within each group that comes "before T". I.e. it assumes your data is sorted by `DEPTH` as your example. The following also assumes that the minimum within each group is always 0.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE,text="
SITE_ID, DEPTH, METALIMNION, TEMP_FIELD, EPI.T, EPI.D
A,      0,          ,          25.0,   26.0,   2     
A,      1,          ,          26.0,   26.0,   2
A,      2,          ,          27.0,   26.0,   2
B,      0,          ,          10.0,   10.25,  5
B,      5,         T,          9.0,    10.25,  5
B,      10,         ,          11.0,   10.25,  5
B,      15,        B,          21.0,   10.25,  5")


library(dplyr)

max_by_grp <- df %>% 
  group_by(SITE_ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() <= min(which(METALIMNION=="T"), n())) %>%
  summarise(max = max(DEPTH))

print(max_by_grp)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  SITE_ID   max
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A           2
#2 B           5

res <- merge(df, max_by_grp)
print(res)
#  SITE_ID DEPTH METALIMNION TEMP_FIELD EPI.T EPI.D max
#1       A     0                     25 26.00     2   2
#2       A     1                     26 26.00     2   2
#3       A     2                     27 26.00     2   2
#4       B     0                     10 10.25     5   5
#5       B     5           T          9 10.25     5   5
#6       B    10                     11 10.25     5   5
#7       B    15           B         21 10.25     5   5
```

Adding the mean temperature to that summary is trivial.